# Display input field on selected value using Ajax or Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I was wondering how I can display an input field only when someone chose a value inside the select box which the value in the select box is retrieved from the database.

Here below is an apercu of my code

```
    <select id="region" >
    <option value="">Select Region</option>
    <?php
    $Region = $category->getAllRegion();
    if($Region){
    while($result = $Region->fetch_assoc()){
    ?>
    <option value="<?php echo $result['regionId']; ?>"><?php echo $result['regionName']; ?></option>
    <?php } } ?>
    </select> 

    <input type="text" name="town" id="town" />
```

and here is the javascript. I tried doing it this way but didn't work for me. Anyone with a better proposal whether it is using Ajax or JS is welcomed

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#region").change(function(){
  if($(this).val()=="<?php echo $result['regionId']; ?>")
   {    
    $("#town").show();
   }
   else
     {
    $("#town").hide();
    }
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Here is an example of conditional releasing content on a page using angularjs.  A basic example if text in the textbox matches a value: [link](https://codepen.io/josdea/pen/BRLVdp)

Comment: Ok. But what I'm trying to say is I want the select box to get its value from the database and when the user selects a value, the input field will automatically show, if not it will remain hidden.

Comment: Is $result['regionId'] a know value in the javascript? i.e. it is always the same for every user?

Comment: no, it is not the same. There are 20 regions, so that's why i want to use PHP to retrieve the region using the id

Comment: is this what you are looking for [link](https://jsfiddle.net/yd85cnf1/)

Comment: Yeah, that is kind of what I'm looking for, Bu to be exact,  I want the select options to be retrieved from the database using PHP and mysql query

Comment: You could only use that jquery part and replace 1 with the expression you wanna compare

Comment: I tried but it didn't work for me. Can you please illustrate?

Comment: I just tried it. It is not working correctly. It only display the input box when I choose the first option in the select box

Comment: could you share the rendered html page ? probably its due to $result['regionId'] couldn't be found in jquery as it can be accessed only inside loop

Comment: Yeah, I thought so. But I'm trying to figure out where the problem is

Comment: what are you trying to do with that if statement in jquery ? what is the statement ?

Comment: I just want to get the value of each option inside the database and if there is a value, it will display the input field.

Comment: do you mean to say  you wanna show input field for all select options except the one which don't contain the empty value attribute ?

Comment: Yeah, that’s what I mean . But it is except for the one which has an empty value ***

Comment: try if( $(this).val() !== "" )

Comment: Thank you so much. I had already figured it out while I was on the road but thank you so much for your assistance!